The Barking Question
"Uncle I'm bored!" exclaimed young Baz on their journey to London.
"I have an odd-one-out puzzle for you" said the elder.
On a piece of paper, he wrote the words "AH, EM, UH, OK."
"You have until Barking to work it out."

The odd-one-out is:

 UH

Because the other three are all...

 ...names of trees with the middle letter missing: A[S]H, E[L]M, O[A]K.

 'Barking' is a relevant clue because trees have bark, and the use of 'elder' (another type of tree) in the text is an additional clue!


indeed - well done and also rot13 Onexvat hc gur jebat gerr


 It's EM, which comes before Barking to form "embarking".

Another idea that leads to the same answer:

 "You have until Barking to work it out" can be interpreted as that Baz only should have the bolded phrase to work with. All choices except EM have one letter in common with it.


But Barking is a rail / tube station in East London. I was hoping it would be relevant.

Good but not quite what I was looking - the answer is lacking a quality that the others positively share

I have another idea but it would probably be farther off.

@BenjaminWang OP didn't add a knowledge or geography tag though.
